# Scrolling both Horizontal and Vertical

Tags: iphone

I'm developing an application in which there are 5 picture and they should scroll both way 
horizontal and vertical. 
E.G :- If I scroll horizontal from first picture then second picture should display and if I scroll Vertical from second then third should display.

Please help if anyone has some idea about it.

Thank you.

Comment: I have made UIScrollview and add UIImageView in scrollview its work perfectly for horizontal scroll but i don't know how to scroll verticle so another image display

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIScrollView and add your pictures (UIImageViews) as subviews to it. Arrange their frames in the desired order, then set the scroll view's contentSize to the total size of your views. The scroll view's bounds and contentOffset determine what is visible.

To better understand how scroll views work imagine that the scroll view is a "window" through which you can see a part of a large canvas (*content*). The frame of the scroll view is the size of the "window", its bounds is the content. Scrolling changes the bounds' origin, shifting the "window". Zooming changes the bounds' size, affecting how much is visible. To work properly a UIScrollView must know its contentSize (by default it's always (0,0,frame width, frame height)).

Comment: Thanks but how can i know when user scroll horizontal or vertical way?

Comment: See -scrollViewDidScroll: method of the UIScrollViewDelegate protocol, where you can examine the scroll view's contentOffset property.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look for [Three20](http://github.com/facebook/three20) library. In the code samples you will see `ScrollViewTestController`. Use the whole code files (.h and .m) and then try to override the flipping part of code to get the same functionality as it is in horizontal direction.

Hope this helps.

Thanks,

Madhup

Comment: I have downloaded Three20 as per your given link but it's not working